# Using variable to access Excel Cells in table range from powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I would like to get text from a cell in a table range.

I have multiple values in variables for cells in a table like: Cells(1, 3), Cells(2, 2)... and so on.

But nothing works. It looks for me as the comma is the issue - even if the script works, than it takes only first index (x) from the cells range.
If I'm using string / fixed values like:

`$myData.Add( $srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( 1, 3 ).text )`

everything works fine.

How can I get desired effect?

```
 $myData.Add( "`n" )
    foreach( $table in $tablesData.keys ) {
      foreach( $index in $tablesData.$table.keys ) {
        $x = $tablesData.$table.$index.x
        $y = $tablesData.$table.$index.y
        $xy = "$x, $y" # test variable 01
        $comma = [char]44 # test variable 02

        "{0}.Range( $table ).Cells( {1}$comma {2} ).text" -f $srcWorksheet, $tablesData.$table.$index.x, $tablesData.$table.$index.y # test 01
        $srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( $x, $y ).text } # test 02
        $srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( "$xy" ).text # test 03
        $srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( "$x `, $y" ).text # test 04

        $myData.Add( ??? ) # how to make it work?
      }
    }
    $myData | Out-File -FilePath $dstFile
```

EDIT:
It also works when I'm using:
`$srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( $x, 1 ).text`
or
`$srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( 2, $y ).text`
So it have to be an issue with comma used in Cells()...

Comment: What produced $myData? Are you using the ImportExcel module? `Find-Module -Name ImportExcel`

Comment: Note - if you absolutely *must* use Excel COM, it's an order of magnitude faster to read a range into a multidimensional array, e.g. ```$v = $srcWorkSheet.Range($table).Value2```, modify the array in-memory and then write it back with ```$srcWorkSheet.Range($table).Value = $v``` than it is to peek and poke individual cell values one at a time as you only have to cross the COM boundary twice, instead of once per cell...

Comment: If `$srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( 1, 3 ).text` works, but `$srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( $x, $y ).text` doesn't, the problem must be with the values stored in `$x` and/or `$y`.

Comment: @mclayton Thank you very much, it's much better solution.

Comment: But I would like to know out of curiosity how to fiks it? I have checked also that when I'm using ``$srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( $x, 1 ).text`` or ``$srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( 2, $y ).text`` it also works. So it have to be issue with comma...

Comment: @Slawowid, does it work if you do the following? `$x = 1; $y =2; $srcWorksheet.Range( $table ).Cells( $x, $y ).text`? With your original `$x` and `$y` values, what to `$x.GetType().FullName` and `$y.GetType().FullName` report?

Comment: @mklement0 Yes! Thank you it should have been obvious. Those data were "string" not "int" as it should be...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your comments, those have solved my problem.

The answer and working solution is to force integer value on data:

```
        [int]$x = $tablesData.$table.$index.x
        [int]$y = $tablesData.$table.$index.y
```